# A list of some of absolutely convergent series together.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, absolute-convergence

I have worked on a topic related to the sequence and series. In this way, I need to have some series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ such that they are absolutely convergent. I studied some books such as the calculus (louis leithold or thomas or rudin ,...).Also I checked some websites on internet.

> But now I am looking for " a list of some of absolutely convergent series on a sheet together" (I mean for example some of them recorded on a sheet, such as integral formulas lists, my favorite is they will be special or well-known series or have a closed forms).

I pretty appreciated any help. thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it's fundamentally impossible to create such a list, by Cantor's diagonal argument.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. There are multiple examples of absolutely convergent series, but what does it mean that they will be absolutely convergent *together*?

Comment: @Lukas Rollier I did not mean all the series, but I look for some of them.

Comment: @ gt6989b, Yes I know, but I mean for example some of them recorded in a sheet, such as integral formulas lists.

Comment: @LukasRollier: the set of formulas is countable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the set of series is not

Comment: @LukasRollier: the OP is probably looking for intentional rather than extensional answers. By the way, it is impossible to write down *a single* series in extension.

Answer (score 1):

- All geometric series with a common ratio in $(-1,1)$;
- All Riemann zeta series with the exponent $>1$;
- A lot of Taylor expansions, within their radius of convergence ($(1+x)^\alpha, \log(1+x)$, $e^x, \cos x, \sin x\cdots$).